PHP Parse error: Unexpected character "" (ASCII 26)
I am pretty new to Laravel. With Laravel 11, I have this error which I couldn't fix...
In php artisan tinker, when I run:
App\Models\User::factory()->create()
I get this error:
PARSE ERROR  PHP Parse error: Unexpected character "" (ASCII 26) in vendor\psy\psysh\src\Exception\ParseErrorException.php on line 44.
This is my UserFactory.php
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

/**
 * @extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory<\App\Models\User>
 */
class UserFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The current password being used by the factory.
     */
    protected static ?string $password;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function definition(): array
    {
        return [
            'first_name' => fake()->firstName(),
            'last_name' => fake()->lastName(),
            'email' => fake()->unique()->safeEmail(),
            'email_verified_at' => now(),
            'password' => static::$password ??= Hash::make('password'),
            'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Indicate that the model's email address should be unverified.
     */
    public function unverified(): static
    {
        return $this->state(fn (array $attributes) => [
            'email_verified_at' => null,
        ]);
    }
}

and User.php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

// use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * Get the attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @return array<string, string>
     */
    protected function casts(): array
    {
        return [
            'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
            'password' => 'hashed',
            'is_admin' => 'boolean',
        ];
    }
}

ParseErrorException.php is the same as default, I didn't change anything:
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of Psy Shell.
 *
 * (c) 2012-2023 Justin Hileman
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace Psy\Exception;

/**
 * A "parse error" Exception for Psy.
 */
class ParseErrorException extends \PhpParser\Error implements Exception
{
    /**
     * Constructor!
     *
     * @param string    $message    (default: '')
     * @param array|int $attributes Attributes of node/token where error occurred
     *                              (or start line of error -- deprecated)
     */
    public function __construct(string $message = '', $attributes = [])
    {
        $message = \sprintf('PHP Parse error: %s', $message);

        if (!\is_array($attributes)) {
            $attributes = ['startLine' => $attributes];
        }

        parent::__construct($message, $attributes);
    }

    /**
     * Create a ParseErrorException from a PhpParser Error.
     *
     * @param \PhpParser\Error $e
     */
    public static function fromParseError(\PhpParser\Error $e): self
    {
        return new self($e->getRawMessage(), $e->getAttributes());
    }
}

I've tried:

Checked for Hidden Characters
Ensured that PHP files are saved with UTF-8 without BOM
Checked composer

composer install
composer update


Cleared cache

php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear

5.Another factory is working without problem
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

/**
 * @extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory<\App\Models\Release>
 */
class ReleaseFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function definition(): array
    {
        return [
            'version_name' => fake()->firstName(),
            'summary' => fake()->text(),
        ];
    }
}


Can you also share the code that causes the problem; along with your attempts to resolve the problem?

Is there any more to the error message that provide a hint? If you're using linux, try this from the project root, which may help find which file it is: find . -iname '*.php' -exec php -l '{}' \; | grep -v '^No syntax errors'

@aynber I am afraid I don't have any other hint, nor do I know how to find. I'm on windows.

Try to reduce your setup to any working state. Out of curiosity: if you are new to Laravel, why do you need to use PsySH? The error message looks completely unrelated to the code you've shared

@NicoHaase It's built into Laravel, part of the Artisan tinker console environment

That is ASCII control SUB, Ctrl-Z. It is used as Windows end-of-file character. But my first impulse would be to replace most backslashes, \ , with slashes /.

@NicoHaase, I am not using PsySH it intentionally. I thought it is enabled by default with the Laravel installation. I will try to reduce the setup to any working state.

@JoopEggen Changing the slashes would most likely break the code. It does sound like one file has a bad ending character, though

I bring down UserFactory.php and User.php to bare minimum and I still get the same error. And how come App\Models\Release::factory()->create() is working without problem?? I think it's quite a small mistake, and it's so frustrating not being able to identify it...

If you open php artisan tinker and do User::find(1);, do you get the same error? If so, the error is in that file, if not, the error is most likely in UserFactory.

I get result with User::find(1);, no error. But I still can't figure what is wrong with the UserFactory... :(

I found it! Apparently the invalid character was in my tinker input. When I just retyped App\Models\User::factory()->create() from scratch, it worked. ‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️ Thank you all very much for your comments.
